# Doctrine2 get object without relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

An user has one role.
A role has zero or many users.

I would like to find roles without users.

I need to have this query **without using IN or NOT IN**

I tried with join:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('role');
$qb
    ->leftJoin('role.users', 'users')
    ->where('users IS NULL')
```

without join

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('role');
$qb
    ->where('role.users IS NULL')
```

with id:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('role');
$qb
    ->leftJoin('role.users', 'users')
    ->where('users.role != role')
```

Do you have other ideas? Do I have no other choices than to use IN / NOT IN queries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find roles that don't have any users by using a count query

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('role');
$qb ->addSelect('COUNT(users.id) AS total_users')
    ->leftJoin('role.users', 'users')
    ->groupBy('role.id')
    ->having('total_users = 0')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: I'm having Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected. Any idea why?

Comment: @goto change count to `COUNT(users.id)`

Comment: thanks, but do you know how to avoid the 8250 queries done by doctrine :O

Comment: @goto i don't have any idea regarding 8250 queries and i guess above query will be executed as one query not for each role for for each user individually

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway! i will look more information about the increase of queries