# Convert SQL with subquery to Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have follow database structure:

```
List item

trips (ManyToMany to tags over table trips_tags)
+----+----------------+
| id |      name      |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Czech Republic |
|  2 | Germany        |
|  3 | Poland         |
+----+----------------+

tags
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Mountains |
|  2 | Beach     |
|  3 | City      |
+----+-----------+

trips_tags
+----------+---------+
| trips_id | tags_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |
|        1 |       2 |
|        3 |       1 |
+----------+---------+
```

I need to select trips which has all tags I specify.

- Need trips for tags Mountains as Beach I get only Czech Republic.
- Need trips only for tag Mountains, get Czech Republic and Poland

I wrote a simple SQL

```
SELECT trip.name, trip.id
FROM trips AS trip
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(trip_tag.tags_id) 
    FROM trips_tags AS trip_tag 
    WHERE trip_tag.tags_id IN (1, 2) 
      AND trip_tag.trips_id = trip.id
) = numberOfTags`
```

Now **I have a problem to write this SQL in DQL**. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: In what framework are you working? 
Normally if you work with Doctrine you make Entity Classes and you use Doctrine PHP Comments and make relationships in these classes. 

You should never write a naked query like that. Everything should be handled in Doctrine itself.

Comment: I'm working in Nette FW. I have no problem with design of entities, but I didn't know how to create a query in DQL :)

Comment: Fair enough, it wasn't clear to me whether you got that part or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have many to many relationship between trips and tags, Its better to go with doctrine way and define your entites and relate them as many to many like

```
class Trip
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="trips")
     * @JoinTable(name="trip_tag")
     */
    private $tags;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tag s= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Tag
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Trip", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    private $trips;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->trips = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then build your DQL with some aggregation

```
$tagIds = [1,2];
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('trip');
$qb ->addSelect('COUNT(tags.id) AS total_tags')
    ->leftJoin('trip.tags', 'tags')
    ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('tags', $tagIds))
    ->groupBy('trip.id')
    ->having('total_tags = @numberOfTags')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

[**Many-To-Many, Bidirectional**](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

[Doctrine2 get object without relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921729/doctrine2-get-object-without-relations/29921968#29921968)

[Symfony2 - Doctrine2 QueryBuilder WHERE IN ManyToMany field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576818/symfony2-doctrine2-querybuilder-where-in-manytomany-field/25577184#25577184)

Comment: Yes, it's looks good and works it but I need to get array of Trips entities? Now I get only array of total_tags values. It is possible?

Comment: @iwory you can add `->select('trip')` in your query to get collection of trips

Comment: Yes, we are approaching :) Now I get array where every  item has two keys -> Trip entity and total_tags value. It's possible to remove total_tags key and get only clear array of Trips? Thx a lot

Comment: @iwory I guess you need to transform it manually , not sure about this.