# Doctrine2: Many-to-Many select all entries, with/without relations

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a many to many bidirectional relation in my app, right like in [official guide](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

Using a relational model `User` <-> `Group` from the link above - lets say I want to select all entries from `Group` entity with the following condition

```
1) Select all groups that have at least one user related to a group.
2) Select all groups that have no users in it.
```

I can't figure out how to prepare a correct DQL, any ideas please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure DQL you could write is as

```
SELECT g, 
       COUNT(u.id) AS total_users
FROM Entity\Group g
LEFT JOIN g.users u
GROUP BY g.id
HAVING total_users >= 0
```

[Doctrine2 get object without relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921729/doctrine2-get-object-without-relations/29921968#29921968)